# SQL select query retrieval blank return

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to retrieve distinct entities from a column, all of which start with a vowel. The query looks like this :

```
Select DISTINCT column_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name LIKE '[aeiou]%';
```

It's not giving compilation errors, but it's not returning anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
Select DISTINCT column_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[aeiou]';
```

`LIKE` wildcard patterns do not support character classes, except in a couple of databases that extend the definitions of the `LIKE` pattern.

Also, you might want:

```
WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU]'
```

If you have a case-sensitive collation.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But do we have to use REGXP everytime when trying to search for character patterns, or there are alternate options?

Comment: @Titichh . . . You can deconstruct the string (i.e. take the first letter) or use lots of `or`s.